# Open and read from excel file

Tags: excel, vba

**Edit:** After `user3561813` the suggestion of adding `"/"`, it now read the first file. I have an out of range error message `"9"`. It does read the first file correctly. Ultimately I am trying to open each file, and read the name and age (this is a testing not the real production form). And retrieve the values back to my main worksheet.

[image]

**Original question**

I am trying to read hundred of excel forms in a folder, read a particular cell position, and record them into my testing worksheet. I googled this tutorial and tried to write my code. But when I execute the Getting Folder function, selected a folder path, it does not loop the excel files I have. (or record their names)

```
'Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7x1T4s8DVc0
Sub GettingFolder()
Dim SelectedFolder As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select folder"
    .ButtonName = "Confirm"
    .InitialFileName = "U:\"

    If .Show = -1 Then
        'ok clicked
        SelectedFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        MsgBox SelectedFolder
        ' This is where I want to call my function
        LoopFiles (SelectedFolder)
    Else
        'cancel clicked
    End If
End With
End Sub

' Source: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/files-in-a-directory.html
Sub LoopFiles(path As String)
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

' Avoid Screen flicker and improve performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Fixed per suggestion below..
directory = path & "\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""
    i = i + 1
    j = 2
    Cells(i, 1) = fileName
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
        Workbooks("Testing.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, j).Value = sheet.Name
        j = j + 1
    Next sheet
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop

' Reset the screen update setting
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you explain what `it does not allow me to execute it` means you would greatly increase your chances of getting answers.

Comment: Does the `fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")` actually return a non-empty string ? Does the value of `path` argument end with a backslash ? You might want to print the result of `directory & "*.xl??"` to make sure it is a value that when used as the argument of `Dir()` should return what you expect.

Comment: Be aware that the `path` when received in LoopFiles doesn't have a trailing backslash so your `filename = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")` won't produce a proper path, which means that Dir will return an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the `path` variable may not contain a trailing backslash. This causes the following code in your `LoopFiles(<>)` SubRoutine to be inaccurate:

```
directory = path
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
```

Filename would look something like: `c:\users\name\documentshello.xlsx`

Try changing the above code to:

```
directory = path & "\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
```

Does that fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks, this solved the opening problem, and now I have an out of range error right after the first file is opened. Ultimately I am trying to read a field of each file, and retrieve that value back to my main worksheet.

Comment: I suspect it is in my loop For each sheets...?

Comment: @George If it's one of the workbooks that is opened by looping through the directory, you have to recognize that the workbook is closed before looping to the next file. So, when you explicitly reference `Testing.xlsm` the second time through the loop, it doesn't exist in the scope of the procedure. Without knowing what you would actually like to happen here, I can't give perfect results. If you can't figure it out based on the info, follow up with more details about that specific chunk of code and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks, I will look more into it, if needed I will open another question... I really appreciated your patient and suggestion. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question!  This should do it for you.  Modify as needed.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xlsx"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
  Row = 1
'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Row).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
      Row = Row + 1
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect Answer.